# No Kerberos creds in keytab for principal HTTP/XXXX

Tags: java, websphere, single-sign-on, kerberos, jaas

Hello everybody (sorry for my english), I am using this library (which is a filter for SSO login with kerberos/spnego):

http://spnego.sourceforge.net/

I have an application developed with java(spring) which is deployed in IBM Websphere 8.5.5.8 (ibm jdk 1.7). The deploy is ok.

The library that I mentioned (spnego.jar) is put in the next path:
[WAS_HOME_INSTALL]/AppServer/lib/ext/

I have the krb5.conf file and login.conf file added as jvm parameters in Websphere.

After Deploy I start the application, and when its trying to do the authentication appears the next message:

> No Kerberos creds in keytab for principal
>   HTTP/PWAS02.olympus.corp@OLYMPUS.CORP

Here is the log file:

```
[2/28/18 17:03:22:996 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 JAAS config: debug=true
[2/28/18 17:03:22:996 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 JAAS config: principal=HTTP/PWAS02.olympus.corp@OLYMPUS.CORP
[2/28/18 17:03:22:996 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 JAAS config: credsType=accept only
[2/28/18 17:03:22:996 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 config: useDefaultCcache=false (default)
[2/28/18 17:03:22:996 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 config: useCcache=null
[2/28/18 17:03:22:996 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 config: useDefaultKeytab=false
[2/28/18 17:03:22:996 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 config: useKeytab=/Apps/SSOpoc/SPNEGO/appsvr.keytab
[2/28/18 17:03:22:997 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 JAAS config: forwardable=false (default)
[2/28/18 17:03:22:998 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 JAAS config: renewable=false (default)
[2/28/18 17:03:22:998 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 JAAS config: proxiable=false (default)
[2/28/18 17:03:22:998 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 JAAS config: tryFirstPass=false (default)
[2/28/18 17:03:22:998 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 JAAS config: useFirstPass=false (default)
[2/28/18 17:03:22:998 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 JAAS config: moduleBanner=false (default)
[2/28/18 17:03:22:998 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 JAAS config: interactive login? no
[2/28/18 17:03:22:998 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 Try keytab for principal=HTTP/PWAS02.olympus.corp@OLYMPUS.CORP
[2/28/18 17:03:23:006 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 No Kerberos creds in keytab for principal HTTP/PWAS02.olympus.corp@OLYMPUS.CORP
[2/28/18 17:03:23:007 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 Login successful
[2/28/18 17:03:23:007 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 kprincipal : HTTP/PWAS02.olympus.corp@OLYMPUS.CORP
[2/28/18 17:03:23:008 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 HTTP/PWAS02.olympus.corp@OLYMPUS.CORP added to Subject
[2/28/18 17:03:23:008 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 Attempting to add KeyTab to Subject for HTTP/PWAS02.olympus.corp@OLYMPUS.CORP
[2/28/18 17:03:23:008 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 find keys for HTTP/PWAS02.olympus.corp@OLYMPUS.CORP
[2/28/18 17:03:23:008 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O [JGSS_DBG_CRED]  WebContainer : 1 No keys to add to Subject for HTTP/PWAS02.olympus.corp@OLYMPUS.CORP
[2/28/18 17:03:23:027 PET] 00000082 SystemOut     O 17:03:23.027 [WebContainer : 1] INFO  SpnegoHttpFilter - creds=
--- GSSCredential ---
    Number of mehanism credentials: 1

[1] SPNEGOCredential
Owner:  default
Usage:  Accept Only
Start Time: 2/28/18 5:03 PM
InitLifetime:   0 Seconds
AcceptLifetime: INDEFINITE 

--- End of GSSCredential ---
```

This is my login.conf file when I use Java native library

```
spnego-client {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};

spnego-server {
    com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    useKeyTab=true
    keyTab="file://C:/Apps/SSOpoc/SPNEGO/appsvr.keytab"
    storeKey=true
    isInitiator=false
    useTicketCache=false
    principal="HTTP/OLYSOFT-WS.olympus-corp.info@OLYMPUS-CORP.INFO"
    debug=true;
};
```

This is the login.conf when I use Java IBM jdk

```
spnego-client {
    com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};

spnego-server {
    com.ibm.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
    principal="HTTP/PWAS02.olympus.corp@OLYMPUS.CORP"
    credsType=acceptor
    useDefaultKeytab=false  
    useKeytab="file:/Apps/SSOpoc/SPNEGO/appsvr.keytab"
    serviceAccountName=appsvr
    debug=true;
};
```

I don´t know which is the equivalent for **storeKey** (which Store key in principal’s private credentials) parameter for IBM login.conf (I think that is the principal reason for the error in my log).

Please I appreciate any help.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: To begin with, what server are you running your HTTP service on? Clients using SPNego will present their creds for `HTTP/server.fqdn@REALM` where server FQDN should match the DNS canonical name _(i.e. resolving name to IP then IP to name should give the same exact name)_ and REALM should match whatever rules are defined in `krb5.conf`. Beware of lower/uppercase mismatches...

Comment: Then, what's inside the keytab? Please check output of `klist -e -k appsvr.keytab`

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I execute the command klist and show this info:

Keytab name: FILE:/Apps/SSOpoc/SPNEGO/appsvr.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   3 HTTP/PWAS02.olympus.corp@OLYMPUS.CORP (arcfour-hmac)

Comment: SPNEGO is supported in [WebSphere out of the box](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/usec_kerb_SPNEGO_config.html), you dont need any third party libraries to use it. Just configure it via admin console.